# Unity Standalone Probobuf C# Port

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to use the Protobuf C# Port that was developed by Jon Skeet's on a Unity project, but I keep getting errors when I try to build and run a stand alone. I have copied over all the .dll files into the assets and things run smoothly while I'm running unity from developer environment, but as soon as I compile and build I get an error about a "filename unkown".

[error image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8S3cAU9r3oTZ1VKbFk5TE55R2M/view?usp=sharing)

I haven't managed to find a solution because it seems that most people run into similar issues using Marc Gravell's version of Protobuf. I'd like to stick to the version that I'm using now since I will be working with several languages for this project.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

-- Solution --

It turns out that I had to go into Edit > Project Settings > Player and change the NET version from 2.0 Subset into 2.0

Comment: please provide the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often find type initialization exceptions occurring because of project reference issues. The two most common causes:

1. Building your application against a newer version of .NET than the library being referenced (e.g. Protobuf library may have been compiled against .NET 4 while the application is being built against .NET 4.5). You could try resolving that by recompiling the Protobuf libs against the same .NET version as your project.
2. The compiler assumes a reference is present, but at run time it is not. You can fix this by adding a reference to the specific library (in this case the .NET library with the `RegEx` object, which is usually System.dll)

Comment: Thank you so much! You were right about the comparability issue of the projects. With this info I was able to find what I needed to fix the issue. Turns out that Unity has a subset of NET 2 and I had to switch it to the full version.